# Elasticserach, search datetime field only for the time

Tags: python, elasticsearch

i have lot of timestamps in Elasticserach, and i want to search for every document where the field "timestamp" matches those that match 11:05 UTC. The timestamp format is

yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

and its type is "date". How can i ignore the months, days, years and seconds and only serach for the time?
Thank you in advance!

I tried to simply search with a query like

```
 query = {
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "timestamp": "11:05"
            }
        }
    }
```

```
 RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'failed to parse date field [11:05] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]: [failed to parse date field [11:05] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]]')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen an answer here yesterday, somehow it got removed.
I did try the following query :

> 

```
query = {
        "query": {"size": 1000,
                  "range": {
                      "timestamp": {
                          "gte": "11:05:00",
                          "lte": "20:05:59",
                          "format": "HH:mm:ss"
                      }
                  }
                  }
    }
```

But somehow it does not return any values, even when there are a lot of timestamp that should match.
The timestamps look like this 2022-12-01T13:46:28.146663 and the type of the timestamp is "date"